# TypeError: require(...).collection is not a function at Object.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, mongodb, node-modules

so i'm trying to build this app with login and create new account features, etc.
The app was running fine on localhost:3000, but all of a sudden it stopped loading and i got an error in the command line.

the files below that have an error are User.js and userController.js.
here is User.js:

```
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs")
const usersCollection = require('../db').collection("users")
const validator = require("validator")

let User = function(data){
    this.data = data
    this.errors = []
}

User.prototype.cleanUp = function() {
    if (typeof(this.data.username) != "string") {this.data.username = ""}
    if (typeof(this.data.email) != "string") {this.data.email = ""}
    if (typeof(this.data.password) != "string") {this.data.password = ""}

    //Get rid of any bogus properties
    this.data = {
        username: this.data.username.trim().toLowerCase(),
        email: this.data.email.trim().toLowerCase(),
        password: this.data.password
    }
}

User.prototype.validate = async function(){
    if(this.data.username == ""){this.errors.push("You must provide a username.")}
    if(this.data.username != "" && !validator.isAlphanumeric(this.data.username)) {this.errors.push("Usernames can only include letters and numbers.")}
    if(!validator.isEmail(this.data.email)){this.errors.push("You must provide a valid email address.")}
    if(this.data.password == ""){this.errors.push("You must provide a password.")}
    if(this.data.password.length > 0 && this.data.password.length < 8){this.errors.push("Password must be at least 8 characters.")}
    if(this.data.password.length >50){this.errors.push("Password cannot exceed 50 characters.")}
    if(this.data.username.length > 0 && this.data.username.length < 3){this.errors.push("Username must be at least 3 characters.")}
    if(this.data.username.length >30){this.errors.push("Username cannot exceed 30 characters.")}

    // only if username is valid, then check to see if its already taken
    if (this.data.username.length > 2 && this.data.username.length < 30 && validator.isAlphanumeric(this.data.username)){
        let usernameExists = await usersCollection.findOne({username: this.data.username})
        if (usernameExists) {this.errors.push("That username is already taken.")}
  }

// only if email is valid, then check to see if its already taken
if (validator.isEmail(this.data.email)){
    let emailExists = await usersCollection.findOne({email: this.data.email})
    if(emailExists) {this.errors.push("This email is already registered.")}
  }

}

User.prototype.login = function(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.cleanUp()
        usersCollection.findOne({username: this.data.username}).then((attemptedUser) => {
            if (attemptedUser && bcrypt.compareSync(this.data.password, attemptedUser.password)) {
                resolve("congrats")
            } else {
                reject("invalid username / password")
            }
        }).catch(function() {
            reject("Please try again later.")
        })
    })
}

User.prototype.register = function(){
    //Step 1 : validate user data
    this.cleanUp()
    this.validate()
    //Step 2: only if there are no validation errors 
    //then save user data into a database
    if (!this.errors.length){
      //hash user password
      let salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)
      this.data.password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.data.password, salt)  
      usersCollection.insertOne(this.data)
    }
}

module.exports = User
```

here is db.js

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config()
const mongodb = require('mongodb')

mongodb.connect(process.env.CONNECTIONSTRING, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true},function(err, client){
    module.exports = client
    const app = require('./app')
    app.listen(process.env.PORT)
})
```

here is userController.js

```
const User = require('../models/User')


exports.login = function(req, res){
    let user = new User(req.body)
    user.login().then(function(result){
        req.session.user = {favColor: "gold", username: user.data.username}
        req.session.save(function() {
            res.redirect('/')
        })
    }).catch(function(e){
        req.flash('errors', e)
        req.session.save(function(){
            res.redirect('/')
        })
    })
}

exports.logout = function(req, res){
    req.session.destroy(function() {
        res.redirect('/')
    })
}

exports.register = function(req, res){
    let user = new User(req.body)
    user.register()
    if(user.errors.length){
        user.errors.forEach(function(error) {
            req.flash('regErrors', error)
        })
        req.session.save(function(){
            res.redirect('/')
        })
    } else{
        res.send("There are no errors.")
    }
}

exports.home = function(req, res){
   if (req.session.user) {
    res.render('home-dashboard', {username: req.session.user.username})
   } else{
    res.render('home-guest', {errors: req.flash('errors'), regErrors: req.flash('regErrors')})
   }
}
```

here is command line error.

```
TypeError: require(...).collection is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jasmi\OneDrive\Documents\complex-app\models\User.js:2:42)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jasmi\OneDrive\Documents\complex-app\controllers\userController.js:1:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: What is the result of `require('../db')`? As that's where the error is coming from

Comment: usually a database collection is not a function. When you do `collection('user')`, you probably want to get `db.userCollections`. 

If the file exports userCollection, you'd want to get it like this: `const { userCollection } = require('../db')`, and then you can do your logic as in the file. As evolutionxbox said above, if you could provide us with the db file it would be easier to accurately give you a solution.

Comment: hi. i updated the question and added the db.js file. thanks

Comment: You are exporting the client itself. You probably want to export a database and then use the collection inside it. try adding `const db = client.db(dbName);` to the db.js and exporting the db variable rather than the client itself. Then require the file and you then can access your specific collection from there. You can refer to this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb to check out their example. Let us know if this doesn't fix it.